# Android Database access from .NET application

Tags: java, android, .net, sqlite

Hi we have an Android app that currently stores its data in xml files and are looking to move it to SQL Lite based database.

The app is a consumer of data and data is added through a windows application after the phone is connected to the PC (Currently both are done through xml files on the SD card)

If the data is stored on a SQLite database, is it possible to locate and connect to the database from a .NET application which can both enter and delete records from it.

Please advise. Thanks,

Comment: This is not really a java or an android question.

Comment: @AhmedT its an android question. Where does an app store the sql database. Can a .NET application access the database file?

Comment: The original question says nothing about Android, it is about accessing SQLite DB from .NET. The tags should indicate what the question is about, rather than what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You will be able to connect and then manipulate a SQLite database from a .NET application. Use a data provider like [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). The downloads are [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

Comment: Hi Ranhiru, thanks for the answer. Where does an app store the sql database. Can a .NET application access the database file?

Comment: I believe (Please correct me if I am wrong) the SQLite database would be in the same location as your application is installed. And when and how do you want your .NET application to access the database? Remotely? Through USB? When mounted as a disk drive?

Comment: You can create the SQLite DB file on the memory card, this way it is accessible to desktop applications when the phone is connected via USB.